# Keepalived running bash script exit codes problem

Tags: bash

I'm running **keepalived** to balance virtual IPs.

I've written a simple **script** to **check** if a **variable is set**, and if it is, **"bypass" the node** and failover to the **"Backup" node**. It exits from what I can tell with the correct variable.

But **keepalived isn't seeing** that **exit code**, apparently. Where have I gone wrong? The script is being run from the `keepalived.conf` file - and yes, it's set as executable. If I "break" the code (with a syntax error), it fails appropriately.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "$vrrpTVIPS"; #for testing purposes only

if [ "$vrrpTVIPS" != "bypass" ]; then
 exit 0
else
 exit 1
fi
```

What should be happening is if `vrrpTVIPS == bypass`, this script should exit with code 1 (which it does when I run it myself and check `echo $?` I get `1`). Why doesn't the keepalived script see this and act accordingly (it logs script exit codes, and it doesn't have any entries for a exit status `1`)?

I've tried reversing this too, but to no avail:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "$vrrpTVIPS";

if [ "$vrrpTVIPS" == "bypass" ]; then
 exit 1
else
 exit 0
fi
```

Added info:
This is the pertinent info from `keepalived.conf` in `/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf`:

```
vrrp_script check_test_override {
        script "/usr/sbin/chktest.sh"
        internal 2
}
```

and inside the V-Instance config later in the file:

```
track_script {
check_test_override
}
```

Comment: What keepalived config are you using to call this script (e.g. `vrrp_script` or similar) ?

Comment: Yes, I posted the copy - paste above in the post for review.

Answer (score 0):

`vrrp_script` takes a `rise` and/or a `fall` argument, as well as `weight` which sets how many errors or successes are needed for OK/KO transition, and how much priority to give based on this change.

I believe these are both undefined by default, so you have to explicitly define them. For example to switch on a single OK/failure exit code, set:

```
vrrp_script check_test_override {
        script "/usr/sbin/chktest.sh"
        interval 2
        weight 2
        rise 1
        fall 1
}
```

Comment: I modified my config and restarted keepalived - no change. Looking at the logs - it appears it is actually rising the priority of the the keepalived node from 100 (what I have manually set) to 102. This leads me to believe keepalived is not processing the "exit 1" in my script appropriately, as again, when I run it from a command line manually I am seeing it exits with 1.

Comment: If you invert the logic does the proirity drop by 2?

Comment: Inverting the logic didn't prove any changes, but I think the problem is occurring because I'm not setting variables correctly to actually be read by the executable script when it's run by keepalived. It's likely a problem with my understanding of scripting/variables - because when i set the variable in the first line of the script itself, everything works as it should.

Comment: To confirm this an alternative would be to write the value to a file, and read that rather than looking at an environment variable?